# Why browsers "edit" the HTML code and make it not compliant to W3C rules?

Tags: html, dom, browser, accessibility, w3c-validation

Good Morning people.

According to the **Italian Accessibility Law** I have to validate the HTML code of my web pages with the [W3C validator](https://validator.w3.org/).

If I use the browser function "**view source code**" and then I validate the code...I have no problem: I get only the real HTML errors made by developers!

But sometimes, I have to "take" the HTML code from the **DOM**, for example in those HTML pages that are "generated" by script JavaScript.
If I do that, I get many errors (hundreds), because the **DOM** code is different from the HTML code that I get from the browser function "view source code".
This way I can't tell real HTML errors (made by developers) apart from  "fake" HTML errors (made by the browser that edited the code).

My final question is: is there a way to tell the browser "dear browser, when I get the DOM, don't put your bad code in it".

Thank you

Comment: No browser does that (or if any do, you would need to provide an actual test case).

Answer (score 4):

Modern screenreaders use the DOM HTML code, i.e. the HTML code from your application which might have been modified by Javascript codes.

So, you have to validate the generated code. The browser does not add bad code, but your javascript does so.

That being said, some browsers might correct bad DOM hierarchy, only if your code is incorrect.

For instance, the following code will be corrected by browsers when viewing source code.

```
 <b><a href="#link">unclosed link</b>
```